# Simple four-operation calculator in Lua

Tags: beginner, calculator, lua

I'm a beginner at Lua and programming in general and I just made a simple calculator and I was wondering where I could make improvements.

```
print("Choose numbers:")
print("Num1:")
local num1 = io.read()
print("num2:")
local num2 = io.read()
print("Choose operator: + / - / * / /")
local operator = io.read()
if operator == "+" then
   local add = num1 + num2
   print(add)     
end 
if operator == "-" then
   local subtract = num1 - num2
   print(subtract)   
end
if operator == "*" then
   local multiply = num1 * num2
   print(multiply)
end   
if operator == "/" then  
   local devide = num1 / num2
   print(devide) 
end
io.read()
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve?

Comment: Could you please explain to me on how to use this calculator? It is a great design and I have tried to use your code. I am new to lua so an explanation would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try some features, typically available from functional languages. For example, functions that is first class values.

```
local operators = {
    ["+"] = function(x,y) return x+y end,
    ["-"] = function(x,y) return x-y end,
    ["*"] = function(x,y) return x*y end,
    ["/"] = function(x,y) return x/y end
}

local function default()
    print "No such operator"
end

print("Choose numbers:")
print("Num1:")
local num1 = io.read()
print("num2:")
local num2 = io.read()
print("Choose operator: + / - / * / /")

local func = operators[io.read()] or default
print(func(num1,num2))

io.read()
```

Comment: The "choose operator" prompt should mention the valid operators instead of hard-coding only some of them.